# Angular ng-repeat concat 2 Json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to get data from 2 jsons and list it in table :

1st 'names.json':

```
[
        {
            "name": "AAAAAA",
            "down": "False"

        },

        {
            "name": "BBBBBB",
            "down": "False"
        },
        {
            "name": "CCCCC",
            "down": "True"
        }
]
```

Second 'data.json'

```
[
         {
            "data": "15%"
        }
]
```

Javascript:

```
app.service('service', function($http, $q){
            this.getNames = function () {
    var datas =  $http.get('data,json', { cache: false});
    var names =  $http.get('names.json', { cache: false});
    return $q.all([datas, names]);
};
});

    app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service) {
     var promise = service.getNames();
     promise.then(function (data) {
     $scope.names = data.names.data;
     $scope.datas = data.datas.data;
});
```

Now i must show it in table HTML :

```
div ng-controller="FirstCtrl"
     <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="name in names.concat(datas)">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
            <td ng-if="name.down === 'False'">{{name.down}}</td>
            <td ng-if="name.down !== 'False'">{{name.data}}</td>
            <td>{{name.data}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I try concat() but it dont work, is there any method to show in table datas from 2 arrays by ng-repeat? Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve the desired using filer easily.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);


function FirstCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.names = [{
    "name": "AAAAAA",
    "down": "False"

  }, {
    "name": "BBBBBB",
    "down": "False"
  }, {
    "name": "CCCCC",
    "down": "True"
  }];
  $scope.datas = [{
    "data": "15%"
  }]

};

app.filter('getvalue', function() {

  return function(name, datas) {

    if (name.down === 'False')
      return name.down;
    else
      return datas[0].data;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td>{{name | getvalue:datas}}</td>
        <td>{{name.data}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```